# Oracle 11g direct I/O and write complete wait

Tags: oracle, io, oracle11g

Last week my database having high waiting time (write complete waits) on disk. I decided to stop all application from using this database. After that I shut down database and decided to use direct I/O option oracle as advised by my vendor last year.

*I cannot put screen shot here because didn't have enough reputation point

So changed value filesystemio_options from ASYNCH to SETALL and started back database. All application continue using this database again. But...

My disk seems more busy then before, but no waiting detected. Is this normal?

*I cannot put screen shot here because didn't have enough reputation point

For disk i'm using MegaRAID. 
c0t1d0 is consist of 6 physical disk.

```
Virtual Drive: 1 (Target Id: 1)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 835.394 GB
Mirror Data         : 835.394 GB
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 64 KB
Number Of Drives per span:2
Span Depth          : 3
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAheadNone, Cached, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAheadNone, Cached, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Access Policy       : Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Disk's Default
Encryption Type     : None
```

Comment: You should post awr reports for the time when the problem happened.

Comment: i'll add later tomorrow